# post dropbox value populated from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

iam trying to populate my dropbox from my database and then retrieve it in my php code...is this possible?

```
<form method="POST">
<select>

while ($fethc_items = mysql_fetch_assoc($items))
{
  $item_id= $fethc_items['item_id'];
  $itemname = $fethc_items['item_name'];
?>
  <option value="<? echo $itemname;?>">Volvo</option>
<?}?>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<? 
 if (isset($_POST['?']))
  {
   }
?>
```

Comment: Yes but use proper php tags etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can..

Try this code. I hope its will help you.

```
<form method="POST">
<select name="item">
    <?php 
    while ($fethc_items = mysql_fetch_array($items))
    {
      $item_id= $fethc_items['item_id'];
      $itemname = $fethc_items['item_name'];
    ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $item_id;?>"><?php echo $itemname;?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['item'])) {

}
?>
```

Thank You!

Comment: what will be in 
`$_POST[?] `
please advise

Comment: you should add name for select tag, and after sumbit the form you will get the input data in the $_POST['item']. Please try this.

Comment: Thank you Ashneel Chand.. All the best for your try :)